# Why is value in console log not showing in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I have a react app where console.log not showing the values in it but it displays the message.
eg,

```
class Sample extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.state = {
                         msg:"Hi"
                     }}
 handleSubmit(event) {
    console.log("Message",this.state.msg);
}


render() {

      return(
        <div >
        <RaisedButton label="Save" onClick={this.handleSubmit}/>
        </div>
      );
    }}
```

Not only state values but
whatever values I gave its not displaying. What will be the issue be? Please help

Comment: Please provide some more context and snippets regarding how `this.state.msg` is initialized and where does that `console.log` statement executed

Comment: Please provide more info, so that we can help you out

Comment: Need more info on this

Comment: @Andreas Please check I have updated.

Comment: Where does `handleSubmit` being called?

Comment: handleSubmit should be outside constructor.

Comment: @Andreas Simply on a button click. When I gave an alert like  _alert(`Message ${this.state.msg}`);_ it correctly shows the value. But I cant figure out why console.log doesn't.

Comment: Can you try `console.log(this.state.msg);`

Comment: It works without trouble with this simple demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/xoo5z9v4qp. I doubt that the problem is on `onClick` props of `RaisedButton`.

Comment: 1. Do you see any errors in console. 2. Is this working `console.log(this.state.msg);` 3. Which browser are you using? 4. Type `console.log` in console, what do you see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer.
It was a small error, I gave

```
console.log("Message" +this.state.msg);
```

changed coma to plus.

Comment: Comma should work unless some code is messing with window.console.log